House painter only using pressure washer to remove oxidization
We are having the exterior of our house painted by someone who comes recommended and has good reviews.
The house has aluminum siding with white chalky oxidized paint.
I was under the impression that he was going to use a chemical wash to remove the oxidized paint, but today when they began to pressure wash they informed me that they are only pressure washing with water.
I'm worried the paint job they are going to do is not going to last, when I told him about my concerns he said this is the process they always follow, and that he would demonstrate by painting a small area of the house to let me see how the paint will stick.
Should I bail at this point and find another painter? Or is this ok? Everything I've read online and been told by other painters is that oxidization needs to be removed with chemicals such as TWP, and even scrubbed, before painting.

Ask for other customers he's done this same technique on and see how they're looking/wearing through the years and seasons.

What guarantee is your painter offering?

What the painter is removing is the dry old flaky paint. If your siding was oxidized it may still be a whitish residue, but pressure washing would blow a hole in the siding.  If there are no holes you don't have oxidized aluminum, only old paint.

Thanks for the comments here, I will ask about a guarantee. RMDman as far as I understand the paint is oxidized, that's why it's chalky and flaking off, but this is according to internet searches and what other painters have told me. Here are just a couple videos that have described the kind of oxidization I'm seeing and the approach to cleaning:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJRz3Y9-Pnc.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RoFXHb2wRXY

If preparing with a chemical wash is important to you, it would have been good to have it spelled out in the contract/pricing. Is the painter open to doing it your way, perhaps at an additional cost?

@klayman, I have seen as much wrong on youtube as correct.  I would never place greater weight on a youtube video over a professional with his reputation on the line.

@klayman,  I could make a youtube video and show how to do everything wrong, but it would still be on the internet.

water is technically a chemical

I just went out and tested the dry surface of the siding, rubbing my hand across it, and there is still chalky residue coming off of it. This seem like something you would want to avoid?

there is much less than before washing, but some still comes off on your hand.

Power washing will remove any loose paint.  If the paint isn't loose, there should be no concern.

There is no need for chemical prep prior to painting
I've both done exterior painting myself and had professionals paint my house.  Never have I seen anyone apply chemicals to the paint to clean or prepare it.  If it is clean and not flaking you can paint over it.  Pressure washing tends to take care of both, but paint may need scraping also.
Sherwin William's guidance

I just went out and tested the dry surface of the siding, rubbing my hand across it, and there is still chalky residue coming off of it.
